Rationalizing the NO2 pi system
Take the molecule NO2 - each terminal O atom has 2 lone pairs and forms 1 sigma bond. This means that each has 1 lone electron left in a 2p orbital which will contribute to the π bonding. So in total, 2 p orbitals each with 1 electron. Since the π system using MO diagram has 5 electrons (2 in bonding π orbital, 2 in non bonding π orbital, 1 in an antibonding π orbital) The peripheral N atom must then have 3 electrons contributing to the pi system (2 sigma bonds, Lewis depicted "lone pair" being antibonding electron in the π system). How is that possible then - it would then have to be contributing to system over multiple p orbitals.


A reason for the downvote so I can improve the question is helpful??
